# What is returned by Java when returning an enum value? A value or a reference?

Tags: java, enums, return

So from my understanding of Java, when you write

```
return value;
```

It might actually return one of two things: the value of 'value', or a reference to 'value', depending on what type 'value' is. To my knowledge, if 'value' is a primitive data type, Java returns the value of 'value', and if 'value' is an abstract data type, like a class, then Java returns a reference to 'value'.

Now, what I'm curious about is the behavior of return with enumerations. If 'variable' is of type enum, does a value or a reference get returned?

Comment: Well, if you want to get technical about it, it will return the value of the reference, not the reference itself.

Comment: let me advertise my answer a little bit to clarify some technical aspects that Jeffrey pointed out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/7034719#7034719 and let me try to confuse you a little bit with this question: what if value is an int[]? Hint: there are only 8 primitive data types in Java...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) is an object that extends `java.lang.Enum` and as such you get back a reference.

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing that up! Google was being surprisingly dodgy in answering that question for me.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is not a primitive.  There is a single unique object instance for each enum 'value' per class-loader.  The return type is a reference to that unique object.